# Is there any way to draw a pie chart using highstock latest version?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using highstock to build some stock charts.

My Code looks like this:-

```
var dataObj =  {
    chart: {
        type: 'pie',
        renderTo : 'container'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Highstock Testing',
        align: 'left',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        x: 27,
        y: 0,
        useHTML: true

    },
    rangeSelector: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            center: ['28%', '20%'],
            dataLabels:{"enabled":false},
            enableMouseTracking:false,
            startAngle: 180
        }
    },
    subtitle: {
        text:'<div style="color: #707070; font-family: ProximaNovaLtSemibold; font-size: 15px;  white-space: nowrap; margin-top: -10px;margin-left: 12px;">testing</div>',
        align: 'left',
        useHTML:true,
        verticalAlign:'bottom',
        y: 0
    },
    credits: {
        enabled:false,
        href: ''
    },
    navigator:{
        enabled:false
    },
    navigation: {
        buttonOptions: {
            enabled: false
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Usage',
        data: [{"y":0,"color":"#80c3f0","visible":true},{"y":100,"color":"#d7d7d7","visible":true}],
    size: '170%',
    innerSize: '185%'
    }]
};new Highcharts.StockChart(dataObj);
```

The above code is working fine in version 2.0.3. But it is not working in the latest version of highstocks(2.1.8).

Can someone explain me how to achive this in latest version of Highstocks?

Answer (score 1):

Its working well even with latest version of HighStock (i.e.  Highstock JS v2.1.8 (2015-08-20). see the working [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ng1kvmxh/23/). You missed to wrap your code inside jquery's document ready or $ . Wrap your code in

```
  $(function (){});
```